# python: combine lists of lists for SQLITE table

Tags: python, arrays, list, sqlite

I need to combine 3 lists into one list so that I can insert it smoothly into sqlite table.

```
list1= [[a1,b1,c1],[a2,b2,c2]]
list2= [[d1,e1,f1],[d2,e2,f2]]
```

Output should look like:

```
combined_list = [[a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1],[a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2]]
```

I tried `sum` `list1 + list2` but both didn't work as this output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from operator import add

a=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
b=[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
print a + b
print map(add, a, b)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
[[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'], [4, 5, 6, 'd', 'e', 'f']]
```

**Edit:**
To add more than two arrays:

```
u=[[]]*lists[0].__len__()
for x in lists: 
   u=map(add, u, x)
```

Comment: If there are more lists to combine? I've to combine 4 lists into one.

Comment: You can repeat it as many times you need. from operator import add

`u=map(add, a,b);
u=map(add, u,c);
u=map(add, u,d);
print u;`

Or try to automate it: `u=[[]]*lists[0].__len__(); for x in lists: u=map(add,u,x);`

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you